# Why won't my ai (Creative Cloud) file save a thumbnail for quick find in Finder?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I used to be able to have an automatic thumbnail when saving an ai file, but now it doesn't work. I'm using the latest/greatest Adobe Creative Cloud. It used to work but doesn't seem to anymore.

Answer (score 1):

For the Finder to show a preview when using QuickLook and in other places, you’ll need to ensure `Create PDF compatible file` is enabled. If you’ve already saved the document with it disabled, you can use `Save As` to turn it back on again.

[image: Create PDF compatible file]

Comment: The latest and greatest Creative Cloud Illustrator 2018 does not have that menu anymore in the file save options! This is no help.